# What's the meaning of 'haler'? [correction: hailer]

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

This doesn't seem to be general reference, because in the context I've seen it used tonight (the London riots), it certainly isn't referring to a coin, or 'a person who hails'.

I've heard it used several times now by mainstream media reporters; they saw someone with a "loud haler".  Here's an [example from Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/bbc5live/status/100683117827850241):

> 5 live producer reports seeing rioter with loud haler - calling for friends, seems very organised

Does anyone have any idea what they mean here by 'haler'?  Even Urban Dictionary doesn't seem to have a satisfactory definition.  My best guess is it's some London street slang for 'megaphone', but can anyone confirm?

Comment: Street slang? No, it's an obvious spelling mistake.

Comment: Voting to close as "too localised" - either a meaningless typo, or ignorant spelling (it *is* Twitter). I'm not sure you can call it "general reference" - (easily looked up anywhere). If you don't know English well enough to see/hear it straight off, you're pretty much stuck.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, I would disagree.  Even with the spelling fixed, it's a term I hadn't come across before and it wasn't in the dictionary in the context of 'megaphone'.  I think it could be a useful question.

Comment: @Jez: Well, I expect we all have odd gaps in our vocabulary, and it *is* true that "loudhailer" is far less common than "megaphone". But if you google it you'll see it's quite common. Providing definitions for such ordinary words isn't what I think EL&U should be concerned with. Face it, it was just a typo plus your lack of familiarity with the right word.

Comment: ...consider this. How long would the question last if we correct the spelling?

Answer (score 5):

OK, I'm now pretty sure it was referring to a megaphone.  [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaphone) a megaphone can be referred to as:

> A megaphone, speaking-trumpet, bullhorn, blowhorn, or loud hailer

Presumably that Twitter message was a typo and they meant **loud hailer**, which is a term for megaphone I've never heard.  Probably be better if it were hyphenated to indicate it's one noun, not an adjective-noun combo.  Oh well.